# Love Elementry OS But the task bar is a problem

Tags: settings, display

How do you make this task bar not overlap on applications. I have a 4 in one Monitor and when I try and work with a window in the middle of the screen, the task bar overlaps and wont go away. I have tried changing the default monitor to top left but that didn't work.
I Am using Elementry OS 6.1 Jolnr

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

they are very careful in some points and very relaxed in others in the same proportion, unfortunately the system is full of problems like this and will probably never be solved.
I would say the system as a whole is a "premium" beta.

Comment: Damm that's a deal breaker. Impossible to work with this on my screen

Comment: I was kind of disappointed. I love the feel and ease of installation but I find it to limiting. Perhaps for people coming from windows to linux , its great ...